# Products and coproducts in the cyclic category

Tags: category-theory

Does the category $\Lambda$ of finite cyclically ordered sets and monotone functions between sets have binary products and coproducts?

Comment: I would say no: $\Lambda$ has products if and only if it has coproducts, and it seems to me that if $\Lambda$ had products, then the same would be true for $\Delta$; the latter category is, however, not cartesian (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84269/products-and-coproducts-in-the-simplex-category)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Big edit : we use betweenness relation

**The category $\Lambda$**
An object of $\Lambda$ is a cyclically ordered set, that is to say a set $A$ together with a ternary relation $R$, the betweenness relation, that satisfies the following properties :

- Cyclicity :For any $a, b, c \in A$, $R(a,b,c) \Longrightarrow R(b, c, a)$
- Asymetry : For any $a, b, c \in A$, $R(a,b,c) \Longrightarrow \neg R(c, b, a)$
- Transitivity : For any $a, b, c, d \in A$, if $R(a, b, c)$ and  $R(a, c, d)$ then $R(a, b, d)$
- Totality : For any distinct $a, b, c \in A$, either $R(a, b, c)$ or $R(c, b, a)$ holds.

An arrow between two objects $A, B$ of $\Lambda$ is a map $f$ that preserves the betweenness : for all $a, b, c \in A, \ R(a, b, c) \Longrightarrow R\big(f(a), f(b), f(c)\big)$.

Let $A=\{a_1, a_2, a_3\}$ and $B=\{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$ be cyclically ordered sets where $R(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ and $R(b_1, b_2, b_3)$. Then there is no product of $A$ and $B$ in $\Lambda$ :

Assume otherwise (for contradiction), and suppose we have a cyclically ordered set $X$ and monotone maps $\pi_A : X \mapsto A$ and $\pi_B : X \mapsto B$ satisfying the following universal property :

> **universal property for product**
>   For any cyclically ordered set $Y$ and monotone functions $f : Y \mapsto A$ and $g : Y \mapsto B$ there is a unique function $h : Y \mapsto X$ such that $\pi_A \circ h = f$ and $\pi_B \circ h = g$.

Let $Y = \{1, 2, 3\} \in \Lambda$, where $R(1, 2, 3)$.

We consider two pairs of arrows, $(f_A, f_B)$ and $(g_A, g_B)$ :

- $f_A : i \mapsto a_{i+1\textrm{ mod } 3}$ and $f_B : i \mapsto b_i$. Call $F$ the function $Y \mapsto X$ given by the universal property. We have $\pi_A(F(1)) = a_2$ and $\pi_B(F(1)) = b_1$.
- $g_A : i \mapsto a_i$ and $g_B : i \mapsto b_{i+1\textrm{ mod } 3}$. Call $G$ the function $Y \mapsto X$ given by the universal property. We have $\pi_A(G(1)) = a_1$ and $\pi_B(G(1)) = b_2$.

The elements $G(1), F(1), F(3)$ are pairwise distinct. Hence, by totality we have either $R\big(G(1), F(1), F(3)\big)$ or $R\big(F(3), F(1), G(1)\big)$.
Suppose $R\big(G(1), F(1), F(3)\big)$, then we must have $R\big(\pi_B(G(1)), \pi_B(F(1)), \pi_B(F(3))\big)$ i.e. $R\big(b_2, b_1, b_3\big)$ which is absurd.
Suppose $R\big(F(3), F(1), G(1)\big)$, then we must have $R\big(\pi_A(F(3)), \pi_A(F(1)), \pi_A(G(1))\big)$ ie $R\big(a_1, a_2, a_1\big)$ which is absurd.

We have derived the desired contradiction, hence there is no product $A \times B$ in $\Lambda$.

Comment: Minor quibble: cyclic orders are usually ternary relations, not binary relations, but I do not think that changes the result.

Comment: @MadeleineBirchfield I totally agree with you, I would have worked with betweenness relation and betweenness relation preserving maps, but I decided to follow the definition of OP.

Comment: @OlivierRoche perhaps I am mistaken, but I thought that monotonic functions were order-preserving functions, which in the case of cyclic orders would preserve the cyclic order.

Comment: @1103_base_6 I'll edit my answer using betweenness, so that all can agree on what we're talking about. Besides, I made a mistake : I considered only increasing maps.